# find substring and get substring before it

Tags: python

I am newbiew in python and I have got a strings which contains `PR` in every string like below

```
This is my PR and its related to me.
This is your PR and its related to you.
```

I want to find `PR` and get the string before it, so my output would like below:

```
This is my 
This is your
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `.split()` method. The code is following:

```
>>> 'This is my PR and its related to me.'.split(' PR ')[0]
'This is my'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` function to find the index of `PR and slice the string till that point.

```
s = 'This is my PR and its related to me.'
pos = s.find('PR')
print(s[:pos])
```

Answer (score -1):

Import re

String = re.findall(r"^\w+"PR)
Print(string)